# Use sed to read file into middle of line

Tags: perl, sed

File A contains this text (assume that "alpha" and "bravo" are arbitrarily long chunks on a single line):

```
alpha {FOO} bravo
```

File B contains an arbitrary amount of text, including all sorts of wacky characters.

I want to replace the string "{FOO}" in file A with the contents of file B. Using sed's 'r' command as follows doesn't work because it inserts the content of file B after that line:

```
cat A | sed -e "/{FOO}/r B"
```

Is there any way, using sed, to end up with a file that consists of:

```
alpha [the contents of B] bravo
```

?  If it would be easier to do this with, say, perl, that's fine too.  But I know even less about perl than I do about sed. ;)

Comment: It is decidedly non-trivial in `sed`; it is easier in Perl. Is there one occurrence of `{FOO}` to be replaced?

Comment: Exactly one, in this case, but there might be an arbitrary number of them.  I realized the difference between using sed and perl here: with sed, you're giving it a string of text (the command) to parse and operate on, so you have to be careful that the data doesn't interfere with parsing the command; but with perl, you're giving it a command that references a variable, so it implicitly takes care of escaping.  (I actually would have just done this in PHP (because I already know how), but invoking the PHP interpreter is way slower and it's just generally less well-suited to processing text.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short `perl` solution:

```
FOO="$( cat replacement.txt )" perl -pe's/\{FOO\}/$ENV{FOO}/g'
```

This will work with any character except `00 NUL`. If you have to deal with binary files, you can use:

```
perl -pe'
   BEGIN {
      open(my $fh, "<", shift(@ARGV)) or die $!;
      local $/;
      $FOO = <$fh>;
   }
   s/\{FOO\}/$FOO/g
' replacement.txt
```

---

Usage:

```
perl -i~ -pe'...' file            # In-place edit with backup
perl -i -pe'...' file             # In-place edit without backup
perl -pe'...' file.in >file.out   # Read from named file(s)
perl -pe'...' <file.in >file.out  # Read from STDIN
```

Comment: Thanks, the one-liner is exactly what I was looking for.  I had to go learn the basics of perl to understand it, but that's a good thing. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If this is Bash on Linux, this seems to work:

```
sed -i "s/{FOO}/$(cat B.txt)/g" A.txt
```

This will directly edit the file `A.txt` - they don't have to be .txt files, I just added those in to make it more obvious.

As @ikegami  points out, this will have problems if there any `/` in the file - also any `\` will probably be ignored.

So in an attempt to solve that, you should be able to use:

```
sed -i "s/\//%2F/g" B.txt
sed -i "s/{FOO}/$(cat B.txt)/g" A.txt
sed -i "s/%2F/\//g" B.txt
```

You won't have to use `%2F` though.

Comment: @ikegami - Might do... You will probably have to escape those with a \ or something...

Comment: Since, according to the OP, "File B contains an arbitrary amount of text, including all sorts of wacky characters," it seems likely that this method won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh_a, '<', $ARGV[0] or die "Failed to open $ARGV[0] for reading";
open my $fh_b, '<', $ARGV[1] or die "Failed to open $ARGV[1] for reading";

my $a;
my $b;
{
local $/;
$a = <$fh_a>;
$b = <$fh_b>;
}

close $fh_a;
close $fh_b;

$a =~ s/{FOO}/$b/;

print $a;
```

As long as your files both fit in memory twice, this should be fine.  The `local $/;` puts the I/O system into 'slurp' mode, reading the whole file in a single operation.

Usage:

```
perl replace_foo.pl fileA fileB
```